# How is arm_neon.h generated or maintained?

Tags: clang, llvm, intrinsics, neon

There is `arm_neon.h` in Android NDK:

`$ANDROID_NDK_ROOT/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/lib64/clang/9.0.9/include/arm_neon.h`

The arm_neon.h content is very long (for me), say, in NDK-r21e, with 73681 lines:

[image]

I wonder how is the arm_neon.h generated from Clang compiler ? Is it generated from some scripts? (Sorry for my poor knowledge for LLVM)

Comment: If you search the LLVM CMake files (or the entire source code) for arm_neon.h, you'll find that it's built from a source file called arm_neon.td. There is only one file of that name in the LLVM source tree, so you don't need to really know CMake to find this. (Which is happy for me, because I know very little CMake.)

Comment: it's a standard header, does it matter how it's generated / how long it is?

Comment: @BenClark Because I have an stupid idea, I would like to implement neon intrinsics in C/C++ (but without SSE/AVX), which is expected to bring debuggable experiance on PC for NEON intrinsics.

Comment: In which case this [search engine of Neon intrinsics](https://developer.arm.com/architectures/instruction-sets/intrinsics/#f:@navigationhierarchiessimdisa=[Neon]) will be useful, and you might also be interested in these [other Neon resources](https://developer.arm.com/architectures/instruction-sets/simd-isas/neon). For PC, Microsoft have documentation on their [C# .Net implementation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.intrinsics.arm?view=net-6.0&viewFallbackFrom=net-5.0n), but that might be relevant.

Answer (score 1):

For Clang compiler, there is `arm_neon.td` as source file, and CMake generates `arm_neon.h` file.

To be precise:

- there is `llvm-project/clang/include/clang/Basic/arm_neon.td`
- there is `llvm-project/clang/lib/Headers/CMakeLists.txt`, providing:

```
# Generate header files and copy them to the build directory
if(ARM IN_LIST LLVM_TARGETS_TO_BUILD OR AArch64 IN_LIST LLVM_TARGETS_TO_BUILD)
  # Generate arm_neon.h
  clang_generate_header(-gen-arm-neon arm_neon.td arm_neon.h)
  # Generate arm_fp16.h
  clang_generate_header(-gen-arm-fp16 arm_fp16.td arm_fp16.h)
  # Generate arm_sve.h
  clang_generate_header(-gen-arm-sve-header arm_sve.td arm_sve.h)
  # Generate arm_bf16.h
  clang_generate_header(-gen-arm-bf16 arm_bf16.td arm_bf16.h)
  # Generate arm_mve.h
  clang_generate_header(-gen-arm-mve-header arm_mve.td arm_mve.h)
  # Generate arm_cde.h
  clang_generate_header(-gen-arm-cde-header arm_cde.td arm_cde.h)
endif()
```

- From the git commit history, there wasn't `arm_neon.td` in the early times:
  [image]